# Selected Item from comboBox is always the same one

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I've created a JComboBox that gets populated with an arraylist of strings. My comboBox gets populated correctly just as I want. My problem comes when getting the selected item: As I print it in a `btnGo.addActionListener` I realize that it is always the same one selected, even though I change the selection and click Go again. Is there a way to make the selection actually change? And can I do the same without having to click Go? Like just selecting the item from the comboBox and instantly do the action.

This is how I check what item is getting selected:

```
String selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And then I print `selected` in the `btnGo.addActionListener`

Comment: To get a satisfactory answer, you're going to likely want to create and post a decent [mcve]. Please read the link to see what this is.

Comment: For instance, for all we know, you might not be getting the selected item within your listener but only printing it there. Don't make us guess -- show us.

Comment: [How to use a combobox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to write an ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) might be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it's possible to execute an action when a comboBox element is selected. You just need to add an ActionListener to your comboBox ; here is a sample code :

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

            Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            if(selected.toString().equals("item1"))
            field.setText("AA");
            else if(selected.toString().equals("item2"))
                field.setText("BB");

        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    getContentPane().add(field);
}
```

Please share source code in order to help you with the selection issue.